# Trying to get property of non-object in shortocde

Tags: loop, filters, shortcode, taxonomy, array

I'm having error in shortcode that "Trying to get property of non-object" on line no 130

Here is code:

```
while ( $our_work->have_posts() ) { $our_work->the_post();

        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "filter" );  //This is the line I'm getting error. which is line no 130.

        $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms

        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term 
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs 
        }

        ........(content is here)
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

filter is custom taxonomy. And I'm using isotope jquery plugin which is working fine in page but giving this error in shortcode. I dont know why this is giving error. Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `global $post` before using `$post->ID`, or better, use `get_the_ID()` instead.

Comment: He's already in the loop, I don't think there's a need to declare it as a global.

Comment: @cristian.raiber if you're inside a shortcode function, there is no `$post` var local to that function.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked . You are genius. Thanks again.

Comment: wasn't aware of that @Milo. Oh well, learned a new thing today :)

Later edit: oh yeah, makes total sense, since it's a shortcode (dooh); wasn't thinking straight.